# How to compute summary statistic on Cassandra table with Spark DataFrame?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, cassandra, statistics

I'm trying to get the min, max mean of some Cassandra/SPARK data but I need to do it with JAVA.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

DataFrame df = sqlContext.read()
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
        .option("table",  "someTable")
        .option("keyspace", "someKeyspace")
        .load();

df.groupBy(col("keyColumn"))
        .agg(min("valueColumn"), max("valueColumn"), avg("valueColumn"))
        .show();
```

**EDITED to show working version:**
Make sure to put " around the someTable and someKeyspace

Comment: This looks very like trying to get someone else to write your code for you. There are various parts to that code. Which do you know how to do in Java, and which are you stuck on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just import your data as a `DataFrame` and apply required aggregations:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

DataFrame df = sqlContext.read()
        .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
        .option("table", someTable)
        .option("keyspace", someKeyspace)
        .load();

df.groupBy(col("keyColumn"))
        .agg(min("valueColumn"), max("valueColumn"), avg("valueColumn"))
        .show();
```

where `someTable` and `someKeyspace` store table name and keyspace respectively.

Comment: I tried this but i get an error:  is this line `.options("keyspace", model)` it says cannot find symbol variable model  and in this line `

Answer (score 1):

I suggest checking out https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/tree/master/spark-cassandra-connector-demos

Which contains demos in both Scala and the equivalent Java.

You can also check out: http://spark.apache.org/documentation.html

Which has tons of examples that you can flip between Scala, Java, and Python versions.

I'm almost 100% certain that between those to links, you'll find exactly what you're looking for.

If there's anything you're having trouble with after that, feel free to update your question with a more specific error/problem.

Answer (score 1):

In general,

compile scala file: 
$ scalac Main.scala

create your java source file from Main.class file:
$ javap Main

More info is available at following url:
http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-class-to-decompiled-java-source-code-classes